# extjs change superclass

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding, superclass, sencha-architect

Is it possible to change the superclass of a Extjs class ?

I would like to do something like that:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.override.MyPanel', {
    requires: 'MyApp.view.MyPanel'
}, function() {
    MyApp.view.MyPanel.override({
        extend: 'MyApp.view.MySuperPanel'
    });
});
```

I cannot do it directly during the `Ext.define();` because I'm using Sencha Architect.